# i am receiving error on <IcandyModel> how to fix it

Tags: typescript, express

candyModel.ts

```
import mongoose, { Schema, Document, Model } from 'mongoose';
import slug from 'slug';

const startUrl = /^(https?:\/)?\/.*/i;

export interface ICandy extends Document {
  name: string;
  price: number;
  boxSize: number[];
  priceDiscount?: number;
  images?: string[];
  logoDescription?: string[];
  createdAt?: Date;
  slug?: string;
  ownerId?: mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
}

export interface ICandyModel extends Model<ICandy> {}

const candySchema = new Schema<ICandy>({
  name: {
    type: String,
    lowercase: true,
    required: [true, 'Please provide name'],
    minLength: [3, 'Name must be at least 3 characters'],
    unique: true,
    trim: true,
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
    required: [true, 'Please provide price'],
    min: [0, 'Price must be a positive number'],
  },
  boxSize: [
    {
      type: Number,
      min: [1, 'Box size must be minimum 1'],
    },
  ],
  priceDiscount: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
  },
  images: [
    {
      type: String,
      validate: {
        validator: (value: string) => startUrl.test(value),
        message: `Please add valid image URL`,
      },
    },
  ],
  logoDescription: [
    {
      type: String,
      enum: [
        'glutenFree',
        'sugarFree',
        'vegan',
        'keto',
        'paleo',
        'dairyFree',
        'nutFree',
        'soyFree',
        'diabetics',
        'probiotics',
      ],
    },
  ],
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
  slug: String,
  ownerId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
  },
});

candySchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  this.slug = slug(`${this.name}`, {
    lower: true,
  });
  next();
});

const Candy: Model<ICandyModel> = mongoose.model<ICandyModel>('Candy', candySchema);

export default Candy;
```

this is my factory function

```
export const updateOne =
  <T extends Document>(Model: Model<T & ICandyModel>) =>
  async (
    slugData: string,
    data: UpdateQuery<T & ICandyModel>
  ): Promise<T | null> => {
    if (data.name) {
      data.slug = slug(`${data.name}`, {
        lower: true,
      });
    }
    const result = await Model.findOneAndUpdate({ slug: slugData }, data, {
      new: true,
      runValidators: true,
    });
    return result;
  };
```

service.ts

```
export const updateOneFact = productServices.updateOne<ICandyModel>(Candy)
```

i am getting error on my service  -> Type 'ICandyModel' does not satisfy the constraint 'Document'.
Type 'Model<ICandy, {}, {}, {}, Document<unknown, {}, ICandy> & Omit<ICandy & { _id: ObjectId; }, never>, any>' is missing the following properties from type 'Document': URL, alinkColor, all, anchors, and 250 more.ts(2344)

How i can fix this error

Comment: What's the mongoose's version?